# Can anyone explain Hazel's dad's dialogue

Tags: grammar

When Augustus calls up and Hazel's dad picks up the phone and says that Hazel's asleep

Hazel says I know what you're thinking.

863 00:42:58,400 --> 00:43:00,439 It's not fair to him.

864 00:43:00,440 --> 00:43:02,041 It's not.

00:43:02,080 --> 00:43:04,079 He doesn't need this in his life.

866 00:43:04,080 --> 00:43:05,599 Nobody does.

867 00:43:05,600 --> 00:43:07,929 A lot more trouble than it's worth.

868 00:43:07,960 --> 00:43:09,971 No, you're right.

Hazel's Dad: 869 00:43:10,520 --> 00:43:12,879 Your mom and I were just saying the same thing.

870 00:43:12,880 --> 00:43:16,324 I mean, it could be time we tossed you out on the street.

871 00:43:16,640 --> 00:43:20,483 Drop you off in an orphanage somewhere, make you their problem.

Can someone explain Hazel's dad's part as English is not my native language so I didn't quite understand this one

Comment: What specifically don't you understand in the dad's words? Is there a particular phrase, or verb form?

Comment: I think OP is asking about the last part, comparing Augustus and Hazel's relationship to her and her family's.

Comment: It could be time we tossed you out on the street. Is he talking about some past time?

Comment: No, it's not a reference to past time. The idiom "It's time [that]" is conventionally followed by a past-tense expression (but it doesn't refer to past time): e.g. "It's time (that) you went to bed" (which means the same as "It's time for you to go to bed"). "It's time we left" (= "it's time for us to leave").  Some speakers use present-tense forms here ("It's time we leave"), with the same meaning; that is not universally considered correct, though.

Comment: Who are Hazel and her dad? Who's Augustus? What is this quote from, and why is it apparently copied straight from a subtitle file?

Answer (score -1):

Hazel and Augustus fall in love even though both know that it may or may not last. Hazel's dad was trying to explain that it's not fair to Augustus since Hazel's disease is unpredictable and for her to give Augustus hope that they may have a life together is unfair because if Hazel were to pass away, then it would leave this hole in Augustus's life - caused by her. Just like how right now Hazel is in her mom and dad's life. If she wasn't ("Drop you off in an orphanage somewhere, make you their problem") then there wouldn't be that hole to fill if in the event she passed.